# Prove that any Nonlinear program can be written in the form...

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm in an operations research course and I'm having great difficulty with the theory portion of the course.

The question asks to show that any nonlinear program can be written in the form

min $$f(x)$$

s.t $$g_i(x)\le0, i=1,2...m$$

where $$f(x), g(x)  : R^n->R$$

Honestly I don't even know how to start this. With the other proof questions, I find some definitions and manipulate to "prove" a fact (ex. proving a set is convex was not hard) but in this case, I'm not sure what assumptions to begin with and what not. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you know the proof where you have the linear program instead of a nonlinear program?

Comment: For us to help you, you need to tell us the EXACT definition of a nonlinear program, as defined in your course for purposes of this question. The exact definition is not fully standardized.